# PostgreSQL: Is there an elegant way to utilize custom json cast function in deep object hierarchy?

Tags: json, postgresql, casting

When converting an object to json in PostgreSQL 9.5, is there any way to ensure that a custom json cast function is invoked for contained objects at arbitrary level in the object graph?

An example:

The custom types:

```
CREATE TYPE Page AS (pageNum INTEGER);

CREATE TYPE Chapter AS (chapterTitle text, pages Page[]);

CREATE TYPE Book AS (title TEXT, chapters Chapter[]);
```

A (pseudo) custom `json` cast function for the `Page` type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cast_page_to_json(Page) RETURNS json AS $$
DECLARE 
  result json;
BEGIN
  SELECT row_to_json(a.*) INTO result
  FROM (
    SELECT $1.pageNum AS num, 'test' AS debug 
  ) AS a;
  RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

—DROP CAST (Page AS json);
CREATE CAST (Page AS json) WITH FUNCTION cast_page_to_json(Page);
```

Now, when running the query below, the custom json cast function is not invoked.

```
SELECT to_json(
        ROW(
        'My First Book',
        ARRAY[
            ROW(
            'Chapter 1'
            ,
            ARRAY[
            ROW(1)::Page, 
            ROW(2)::Page
            ]
            ::Page[]
            )::Chapter
        ]
        )::Book)    ;
```

output:

```
{
  "title": "My First Book",
  "chapters": [
    {
      "chaptertitle": "Chapter 1",
      "pages": [
        {
          "pagenum": 1
        },
        {
          "pagenum": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I know I can write custom json cast functions for each level in the object graph and then invoke the custom json function at the top level - to ensure that the custom json cast function is invoked for instances of the Page type. But is there an elegant way of ensuring this, that does not require custom json cast functions at every level in the object graph?

EDIT: Peeking around in the PostgreSQL source code (version 9.5) doesn't seem to leave much hope, that the `to_json`-function can somehow be tricked into using a defined custom json cast function. (The C function `composite_to_json` seems to be the place, where the conversion takes place)
[composite_to_json](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/json_8c.html#ae7288d34cff8ccbcea7345cf927f4c57)

Comment: Hace you tried using the [`AS IMPLICIT` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html) of the `CREATE CAST` command?

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't seem to help. I think the answer is in [the documentation for `to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) (emphasis mine): "Arrays and composites are converted (recursively) to arrays and objects; **otherwise**, if there is a cast from the type to json, the cast function will be used to perform the conversion". In other words it doesn't explicitly mention respecting casts for arrays and composite/row types.